# Is there an error in "Mathematics for Physicists", p. 107?

Tags: reference-request, vector-spaces

In deriving Bra notation and using it to define the scalar product in terms of the product of a Bra and a Ket, [my text (p. 107)](http://books.google.com/books?id=OGHIo78EX5YC&pg=PA107&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) says that

$$\left<c\right|\cdot\left[\alpha\left|a\right>+\beta\left|b\right>\right]=\alpha\left<c|a\right> +\beta\left<c|d\right>$$

I'm not accomplished enough with either linear algebra or this notation to be sure, but shouldn't this be

$$\left<c\right|\cdot\left[\alpha\left|a\right>+\beta\left|b\right>\right]=\alpha\left<c|a\right> +\beta\left<c|b\right>$$

Comment: Just ignore typos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, a $b$ was turned into a $d$. Your second line is correct.

Comment: Thanks. I had feared that there was something profound (or just obscure) that I might have been missing.